# Can a List be ordered based on the value from a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a List like:

```
List<Users>
```

I have a dictionary like:

```
Dictionary<int, User> userIdToUsers
```

where the `int` is the `User.Id` property value.

Now I want to order by:

1. Is in userIdToUsers dictionary
2. user.Created (DateTime)

So if the user is in the dictionary, it should be on top, and then also order by created date.

Is this possible or do I have to create an intermediary object that combines the User object and a boolean flag?

Comment: Linq has `Select` `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var sorted = source.OrderBy(x => !userIdToUsers.ContainsKey(x.Id))
                   .ThenBy(x => x.Created)
                   .ToList();
```

Change between `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` and `ThenBy`/`ThenByDescending` if you need them in opposite order.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: based on comments clarifying the OP's needs the following LINQ query should do what was requested.

```
IEnumerable<User> ordered = source.OrderBy(x => !userIdToUsers.ContainsKey(x.Id)).ThenBy(y => y.Created);
```

If you want `ordered` to be a `List<User>` then just change the declaration and add a `ToList()` to the query.

Comment: He needs to order the users in a `List` not a `Dictionary`

Comment: @rae1 when I read his conditions it sounded like he just wanted to order by the id then the created time and the `List<User>` had no purpose and was just something he thought was required. Now I'm not sure that's actually the case, but I added another query that uses the list. The OP should have no problem doing what he wants with the info provided. Since his question is unclear I can't really give any better answer... Unless you're interstecting the list with the dictionary then the list serves no purpose at all.

Comment: Yes, it was a bit ambiguous; however, OP wanted to order the items in the list based on the fact that they were in the dictionary and then by date, something along the lines of @MarcinJuraszek answer.

Comment: @rae1 yeah, the version I put in in the edit will do that. However, I still think the OP should be using my first solution. If the items in the list are subset of those in the dictionary then you're just wasting a bunch of cpu cycles getting he intersection of the two. I may be wrong in assuming that but that was the impression I got from the question. My thinking was that the OP was only trying to use the list due to lack of understanding what he could do with the dictionary (asking questions about combining the id in a new object or something when the data is already there).

Comment: No, neither your first nor your second solution would work because the list is not a subset of the users in the dictionary. OP merely wants the users that are *also* in the dictionary to be at the top, hence the `.OrderBy(x => !userIdToUsers.ContainsKey(x.Id))`. In both your solutions you are filtering out any users that not exists in the dictionary, which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: @rae1 alright, I'll take your word for it because when I reread the question with that in mind I agree that's what he wants. I would just delete but sadly I'm discouraged to do so since the answer has net'd +10 rep :|

Comment: Don't worry, I understand. However, you could updated it with your own version of the solution (based on what the OP actually required), for the future generations that come along...

Answer (score 1):

You can also do an in-place sort using a `Comparison<T>` closure:

```
List<User> users = GetUserList() ;
Dictionary<int,User> userIdToUsers = GetUserIdMap() ;

users.Sort( (x,y) =>
{

  // handle null values gracefully. NULL always compares low.
  if      ( x == null && y == null ) return  0 ;
  else if ( x == null && y != null ) return -1 ;
  else if ( x != null && y == null ) return +1 ;

  // at this point, x and y are both non-null,
  // we need to check whether x and y are mapped in the dictionary

  // if one is mapped and the other is not,
  // the mapped instance collates *before* the unmapped instance.
  bool xMapped = userIdToUsers.Contains(x.Id) ;
  bool yMapped = userIdToUsers.Contains(y.Id) ;

  if      (  xMapped && !yMapped ) return -1 ;
  else if ( !xMapped &&  yMapped ) return +1 ;

  // We now know that both are either mapped or unmapped and so collate equal

  // we break the tie by comparing the date/time created property.
  return x.DateTimeCreated.CompareTo(y.DateTimeCreated) ;

});
```